# Graph with ordered bars and using facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidytext

I am trying to make a graph with ordered bars according to frequency and also using a variable two separate two variables using facets. **Words have to be ordered by value given in 'n' variable.** So, my graph should look like [this one](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html) which appears in tidytext book: [image]

My graph bellow, **words are not ordered by value**, what is my mistake?:
[image]
My data looks like the one in the example:

```
> d
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   word    u_c            n
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 apples  candidate 0.567 
 2 apples  user      0.274 
 3 melon   user      0.191 
 4 curcuma candidate 0.105 
 5 banana  user      0.0914
 6 kiwi    candidate 0.0565
 ...
```

Following the code provided in the book and modifying it according to my data, the code looks like this:

```
d %>% 
  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(word, n, fill = u_c)) + 
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  facet_wrap(~u_c, scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip()
```

Here is the `dput` for `d`:

```
d <- structure(list(word = c("apples", "apples", "melon", "curcuma", 
                             "banana", "kiwi", "grape", "curcuma", "grape", 
                             "wood", "satsuma", "melon", "raisin", "papaya", "plum", 
                             "plum", "papaya", "banana", "satsuma", "peach"), u_c = c("candidate", 
                                                                                      "user", "user", "candidate", "user", "candidate", "user", "user", 
                                                                                      "candidate", "user", "user", "candidate", "user", "candidate", 
                                                                                      "candidate", "user", "user", "candidate", "candidate", "candidate"
                             ), n = c(0.56704584625991, 0.273789875549109, 0.190633674260422, 
                                         0.105308514305412, 0.0914084706627656, 0.0565322302654257, 0.0562029558128485, 
                                         0.0547338017954938, 0.0498104102033781, 0.0439600056682254, 0.0393399851625864, 
                                         0.0380903136849362, 0.0370685271783074, 0.0370561875215443, 0.035849706997587, 
                                         0.0352763676677753, 0.0325506180866405, 0.0206825232678387, 0.0198207514650121, 
                                         0.0113753877973113)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                         ), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: This is in fact an issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1902 but has been solved by David Robinson here: https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I can't understand the next steps, this solution is kind of "magicky" as @Cpak metioned ^ ^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the info provided by @GordonShumway and following the answer given by @CPak, bellow I provide the entire and "tricky" and no-elegant way to fix this issue. The almost entire answer (by @CPak) and one more line finally fix the problem:

```
d %>%
  mutate(temp = paste(word, u_c, sep = "_")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(temp, n), y = n, fill = u_c)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_replace(x,"_candidate|_user", "")) +
  facet_wrap(~u_c, scales = "free_y") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

The very relevant comment aside by GordonShumway (because the solution offered there is a little black magicky) - you can create a temporary value to reorder your facet - note I'm using `forcats::fct_reorder` rather than `reorder`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  mutate(temp = paste0(word, u_c)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(temp, n), y = n, fill = u_c)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = F) +
  facet_wrap(~u_c, scales = "free_y") + 
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: The only issue is that your x-axis tick labels aren't quite right - you'll have to edit them through the themes

Comment: Adding this: `scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_replace(x,"_candidate|_user", ""))` solves the problem in a fast but no-elegant way...